# UFW blocks ICMPv6 type 133 router-solicitation Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, icmp, ubuntu-22.04, ufw

In our kubernetes cluster, requests on worker nodes to and from cni0 are blocked by UFW.

UFW log:

```
[1422854.977853] [UFW BLOCK] IN=cni0 OUT=cni0 PHYSIN=vethe715bd6d PHYSOUT=vetha18e0dfb MAC=33:33:00:00:00:02:9e:f5:29:98:19:e8:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:9cf5:29ff:fe98:19e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=56 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
```

I've tried setting interface-specific rules in UFW but to no avail.

UFW rules:

```
Anywhere on cni0           ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere (v6) on cni0      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

To me it seems an appropriate rule for the type 133 is already present in iptables:

ip6tables rules:

```
Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 130
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 131
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 132
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 143
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
```

Anyone an idea how to allow this type of traffic using either UFW or IPtables directly?